# A custom grid component with number (float or integer) support in Lazarus IDE

Tags: grid, components, pascal, lazarus, freepascal

In Lazarus (and any others RAD), a `TStringGrid` visual component is a key component for input/output data from `DataSet` or self-contained. This data is stored in cells as string data type.

I'm wondering if there is any custom grid component that supports float or integer number manipulation and associated methods.

For example:
A grid component which captures input from the user in cells (as usual) and if the data captured is a `String`, internally and automatically convert this data input in corresponding numeric value as `Single` or `Integer` data type for indeed manipulation and display data as usual.

Additionally, if the numeric value for the cell is modified, then also change string representation.

I think a component like this is very useful in case of we need a grid that stored numeric values only (without including a header row, maybe).

Can any of you know if exist a component like that or provide examples or source code about this component?

Thanks a lot and best regards

Comment: [Grids Reference Page](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Grids_Reference_Page)

Comment: In addition, Virtual TreeView  can also be used in grid mode.

Comment: The [help/on-topic] clearly says that questions asking us to find or recommend things are off-topic here. See the section with the numbered list of items (specifically item #4 in that list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on what you mean with "float or integer number manipulation".

If you want to execute **calculations** within the grid, like in a spreadsheet, you should try the fpspreadsheet package (https://sourceforge.net/projects/lazarus-ccr/files/FPSpreadsheet/fpspreadsheet-1.6.2.zip/download, or https://sourceforge.net/p/lazarus-ccr/svn/HEAD/tree/components/fpspreadsheet/). It contains a dedicated grid in which you can enter formulas like in Excel. Each cell stores data essentially as string or number,depending on the data type. See http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/TsWorksheetGrid for an introduction.

If, on the other hand, you have a "matrix" of numbers (2D-array) and want to **display** them in a grid without storing the converted strings permanently like in a StringGrid, you should have a look at the standard TDrawGrid which comes with Lazarus (and Delphi). This grid provides everything that the TStringGrid has except for the strings themselves. Data are converted to strings "on the fly" whenever they are needed and then discarded again. In order to display and edit the numbers you must implement these event handlers:

- `OnDrawCell`: converts the number to be displayed in a particular cell to a string, and paints the string to the canvas of the grid
- `OnGetEditText`, again, converts the number to a string, but now for editing since this string will be passed to the cell editor.
- `OnSetEditText` gets the string from the cell editor and must convert it to a number which must be inserted into the data matrix.

Here is the basic code for the DrawGrid approach. Just add a TDrawGrid to a form and assign the mentioned event handlers. `FData` is a dummy matrix of random numbers which is created by the `CreateData` method.

```
unit Unit1;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, FileUtil, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs, Grids;

type

  { TForm1 }

  TMatrix = array of array of double;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    DrawGrid1: TDrawGrid;
    procedure DrawGrid1DrawCell(Sender: TObject; aCol, aRow: Integer;
      aRect: TRect; aState: TGridDrawState);
    procedure DrawGrid1GetEditText(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer;
      var Value: string);
    procedure DrawGrid1SetEditText(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer;
      const Value: string);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FData: TMatrix;
    procedure CreateData;
    procedure PrepareGrid;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.lfm}

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CreateData;
  PrepareGrid;
end;

procedure TForm1.CreateData;
var
  r, c: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(FData, 5, 10);  // 1st index = col = x, 2nd index = row = y
  for r := 0 to High(FData[0]) do
    for c := 0 to High(FData) do
      FData[c, r] := random*100;
end;

procedure TForm1.DrawGrid1DrawCell(Sender: TObject; aCol, aRow: Integer;
  aRect: TRect; aState: TGridDrawState);
var
  s: String;
  xpos, ypos: Integer;
begin
  if (aRow = 0) and (aCol = 0) and 
     (DrawGrid1.fixedRows > 0) and (DrawGrid1.Fixedcols > 0) then
     exit;

  // Fixed row
  if (aRow = 0) and (DrawGrid1.FixedRows > 0) then begin
    s := Format('Col %d', [aCol - DrawGrid1.FixedCols]);
    xpos := (aRect.Left + aRect.Right - DrawGrid1.Canvas.TextWidth(s)) div 2;
  end else
  // Fixed col
  if (aCol = 0) and (DrawGrid1.FixedCols > 0) then begin
    s := Format('Row %d', [aRow - DrawGrid1.FixedRows]);
    xpos := (aRect.Left + aRect.Right - DrawGrid1.Canvas.TextWidth(s)) div 2;
  end else begin
    // Normal cells
    s := FormatFloat('0.000', FData[aCol-DrawGrid1.FixedCols, aRow-DrawGrid1.FixedRows]);
    xpos := aRect.Right - constCellPadding - DrawGrid1.Canvas.TextWidth(s);
  end;
  ypos := (aRect.Top + aRect.Bottom - DrawGrid1.Canvas.TextHeight('Tg')) div 2;
  // Draw cell text
  DrawGrid1.Canvas.TextOut(xpos, ypos, s);
end;

procedure TForm1.DrawGrid1GetEditText(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer;
  var Value: string);
begin
  Value := FormatFloat('0.000', FData[ACol - DrawGrid1.FixedCols, ARow - DrawGrid1.FixedRows]);
end;

procedure TForm1.DrawGrid1SetEditText(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer;
  const Value: string);
var
  number: Double;
begin
  if TryStrToFloat(Value, number) then
    FData[ACol - DrawGrid1.FixedCols, ARow - DrawGrid1.FixedRows] := number;
end;

procedure TForm1.PrepareGrid;
begin
  DrawGrid1.RowCount := Length(FData[0]) + DrawGrid1.FixedRows;
  DrawGrid1.ColCount := Length(FData) + DrawGrid1.FixedCols;
  Invalidate;
end;

end.
```